# Specified cast is not valid shows in catch er.message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to show this dropdownlist corresponding data in the page but the error occurs.

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from BookRequests where BookRequestId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        TextBox1.Text = reader["BookRequestId"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = reader["BookRequest"].ToString();
        TextBox3.Text = reader["StudId"].ToString();
        TextBox4.Text = reader["Date"].ToString();
        CheckBox1.Checked = (bool)reader["Availability"];
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {

        Response.Write(er.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        BtnsActive(false, true, false, true, false, true);
    }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the value of `reader["Availability"]` ? Debug and tell us. And `.Read()` method is meaningless in such a use.

Comment: Which line does the error occur? What does `reader["Availability"]` give?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code in order to find the exact row where the error occurs? Suspect it is `(bool)reader["Availability"]`. What is the type of the `Availabilty` field?

Comment: Availability is bit and is null...

Comment: in debugger every line is read and only reader is skipped..check box value..

Answer (score 1):

Since `Availability` could be null, you should check for `null` like:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Availability")))
   CheckBox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Availability"));
```

Comment: Bear in mind that Availability might also not even be a bool. It could be an int a string or something else. Just because it represents a bool doesn't mean the database is storing it properly. :)

Comment: @Chris the OP said it's a bit and can be null in a comment. :P

Comment: Ah yes. Foolish of me to have expected that to be in the main question. ;-) Definitely a +1 from me then. :)